# Как снизить загрузку CPU при использовании openCL?

Tags: opencl

Программа в цикле запускает ядро на GPU, потом читает из буфера 16 байт. Время от clEnqueueNDRangeKernel до clEnqueueReadBuffer - 100 мс. Task Manager при этом показывает, что программа загружает одно из ядер процессора на 100%, чего, я считаю, быть не должно. Как побороть такую загрузку CPU?

Nvidia GeForce 9800 GT, driver version: 311.06

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости в OpenCL пока что никак. Здесь этот вопрос также обсуждался:
https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6510-controlling-how-blocking-is-implemented